# Scrollspy effect stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navigation, scroll

The scrollspy effect was working fine, but suddenly it stopped working. I mean the active element of the menu is identified while scrolling the onepage site, when the href links are given as like this href="#id". But It stops working when href is given like "/home#id". I want to use it like this. Since the site uses a common navigation.
This is my code:

```
 / Cache selectors
var lastId,
    topMenu = $("#timenav"),
    topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,
    // All list items
    menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
    // Anchors corresponding to menu items
    scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
      var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
      if (item.length) { return item; }
    });

// Bind click handler to menu items
// so we can get a fancy scroll animation
menuItems.click(function(e){
  var href = $(this).attr("href"),
      offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top-topMenuHeight+1;
  $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
      scrollTop: offsetTop
  }, 300);
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Bind to scroll
$(window).scroll(function(){
   // Get container scroll position
   var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;

   // Get id of current scroll item
   var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
     if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
       return this;
   });
   // Get the id of the current element
   cur = cur[cur.length-1];
   var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

   if (lastId !== id) {
       lastId = id;
       // Set/remove active class
       menuItems
         .parent().removeClass("active")
         .end().filter("[href=#"+id+"]").parent().addClass("active");
   }                   
});
```

can someone help me with this

http://www.drkeenly.com/

Here is a Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/aGjTV/

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Is this still not working? Seems to work fine to me in Chrome unless I'm missing something

Comment: @dcodesmith It works fine without the "/home". We need that /home for navigation purpose

Comment: Doesn't `"http://www.drkeenly.com/home"` and `"http://www.drkeenly.com"` give you the same page?

Comment: @dcodesmith Yes the navigation is common throughout the site. So the "/home" is required for us.

Comment: When you say "not working" what exactly do you mean? I think you should edit your question with more info coz just looking at it I can't figure out what the problem is exactly.

Comment: @dcodesmith its been updated.

Comment: website in question is really slow also on your side ?

Comment: @franchez sorry for that its a testing server

Comment: @winnyboy5 on which browser is it not working ? i tried on chrome and it looks fine.

Comment: @franchez both chrome and firebox.

Comment: @winnyboy5 can you post a fiddle?

Comment: @zword ok i will post in a few minutes

Comment: @winnyboy5 i will check it and reply soon

Comment: But one thing i want to ask.Why the code that you provided wont work for all pages?the navigation will happen in all pages using `href=#id`

Comment: @Zword because the only the home page uses the onepage effect the rest  of the pages need the "/home" to navigate back to the home page.

Comment: That means except for the homepage for other pages when the user clicks on link the user should be directed to home page.Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var item = $($(this).attr("href"));` in your code was creating problem because when you write **href="#id"** it is `var item = $(#id);` but when you write **href="/home#id"** it becomes `var item = $(/home#id);` which is incorrect.I fixed it:

```
scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
  var indexItm = $(this).attr('href').indexOf('#');
  var str = $(this).attr('href').substring(indexItm);
  var item = $(str);
  if (item.length) { return item; }
});
```

---

Another change **filter("[href`*`=#"+id+"]")** which will check for string `#id` within href even in href contains any text before #:

Edited line:

```
menuItems
  .parent().removeClass("active")
  .end().filter("[href*=#"+id+"]").parent().addClass("active");
```

### [Fiddle were only foo is given href="/home#foo"](http://jsfiddle.net/aGjTV/7/)

**Note :** the above fiddle will require a text along with # for Top href also.Otherwise it will set `.active` to all menu items:

```
<a href="#top">Top</a>
. 
. 
. 
<a id="top">top</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var cur = scrollItems!=null?scrollItems.map(...):null;
```

After this line cur is either something or null.
If it's null, then you can't index it like and array, or for that matter get its length with cur.length.

You haven't specified the error, but I bet it's saying "TypeError: cur is null".
The solution depends on what you actually want your code to do, but I'd suggest wrapping the remainder of the function in

```
if (cur) {
...
}
```

Comment: It didn't fix the scrollspy effect. Anyway Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote a custom scroll-spy script, if you wish.

#### Check the DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/L4Gpq/

No need scrollspy plugin anymore and you only need to add in below;

1) `target` to your navi link.

2) Same `class` to your DIVs and `id`: same as your `target` of navi.

#### HTML

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a target="main">Home</a></li>
        <li><a target="story">Our Story</a></li>
        <li><a target="work">Our Work</a></li>
        <li><a target="our-news">Our News</a></li>
        <li><a target="contact">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div id="main" class="content">main</div>
<div id="story" class="content">story</div>
<div id="work" class="content">work</div>
<div id="our-news" class="content">our-news</div>
<div id="contact" class="content">contact</div>
```

#### JQUERY

```
$('nav li a').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('target');
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $('#'+id).offset().top
    }, 500);
});

$(window).scroll(function() {   
    var myArray = new Array();
    $('div.content').each(function() {
        myArray.push($(this).offset().top);
    });
    for( var i=0; i<= myArray.length; i++){
        if($(this).scrollTop() >= myArray[i]){
            $('nav a').removeClass('active');
            $('nav a').eq(i).addClass('active');
        }
    }
});
```

#### CSS

```
li {
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    list-style:none;
    text-decoration:none;
}
li a {
    cursor:pointer;
    text-decoration:none;
    z-index:11;
    padding:0 5px;
}
li a.active {
    background:red;
    color:#fff;
}
.content {
    float:left;
    width:90%;
    padding:45% 5%;
    background:#dfdfdf;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
nav {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    padding:0 0 10px 0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:10;
    background:green;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help. But I am fine with the current script and I already embedded it  in the site. the problem is only the Href attribute with "/". I just need to fix it.