# How to get the currently active/focused element ID

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to change the navigation links color based on whether the particular content div is visible(realy visible on the screen not an overflowed item).Just like 
http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads i am trying.

Currently i am using the scroll event when user scrolls i will check the current id and based on that i have planned to chagne the navigation color link.For that i am using

```
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var ac_id = $(document.activeElement).context.id;
        alert(ac_sc);

    });
```

which is working somewhat proper in IE.Somewhat in the sense , if the user doesnot click on the particular div and scroll it alwys return the first div id.If he clicks on the active one then it returns the active id.Kindly show me the way to achieve it.

**Update** : Fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/2PBE8/ - IE version

Comment: hsakarp do you want any thing like the fiddle shown on the page - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21526583/scrollspy-effect-stopped-working

Comment: [This attribute is part of the in-development HTML 5 specification.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.activeElement)

Comment: yeah Zword.Exactly the same..Thank you..i will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using jquery, have a look at waypoints http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/.

Otherwise you can calculate if an element is scrolled into view using scrollTop and the height of your container.